# UIView.animateKeyFramesWithDuration not animating smoothly

Tags: swift, uikit, uiviewanimation

I am trying to write a blinking animation, but the timing of it feels off. I made a simple version in a playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground
let v = UIView()
v.frame.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
v.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
v.layer.cornerRadius = 100

UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: .Repeat, animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
      v.alpha = 0.0
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
      v.alpha = 0.5
    })
    }, completion: nil)

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = v
```

The view fades from 0 to 0.5 and then appears to stutter at full alpha for a second before resuming the animation. I noticed the same thing in the simulator.

Is there something I am missing about how the keyframes are supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon inspection, I believe the default for your `v` view's `alpha` is `1.0`. This means that after your animation ends for a split second it is at full `alpha` again, and then the animation is repeated. To compensate for this and acquire the effect you want, you may consider setting its `alpha` to `0.0` before you run `XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = v`.

**Updates:**

You can break the animation your code into 4 states.

1. At the start, the `alpha` is `1.0`.
2. The first keyframe changes the `alpha` to `0.0` in 0.5 seconds.
3. The second keyframe changes the `alpha` to `0.5` in 0.5 seconds.
4. At this point, the animation has ended. So the `v` view reverts to state **1** and repeats then animation.

State **4** is where the blink of full `alpha` occurs because the `v` view is going from `0.5` to `1.0` in `0.0` seconds. However, the computer cannot make anything happen in `0.0` seconds (not actually possible because of complicated physics) so the result is a split second flash of full `alpha` as the computer tries to get as close to `0.0` seconds as it can.

To circumvent this you can either set the original `alpha` to `0.5` so that way the animation's state **1** will be the same as the result of its state **3**, or you can add another keyframe that brings the `alpha` back to `0.0` before the animation is over:

Examples:

**Option 1:**

```
//Import Statements
//Configuration and Initialization of v view

v.alpha = 0.5 //<--- This is the key point

UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: .Repeat, animations: {
   UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
      v.alpha = 0.0
   })
   UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
      v.alpha = 0.5
   })
}, completion: nil)

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = v
```

**Option 2:**

```
//Import Statements
//Configuration and Initialization of v view
v.alpha = 0.0 //<-- Make sure to set the original alpha to 0.0

let duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.8
let third: NSTimeInterval = 1/3

UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: .Repeat, animations: {
   UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: third, animations: {
      v.alpha = 0.0
   })
   UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(third, relativeDuration: third, animations: {
      v.alpha = 0.5
   })
   //Key Point Below. Added Another Frame!
   UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(third*2, relativeDuration: third, animations: {
      v.alpha = 0.0
   })
}, completion: nil)

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = v
```

Comment: I understood that the original alpha was 1. I'm wondering why it snaps back to that value between repeats. I found that behavior surprising. I know that CAAnimations are removed when they complete, is it basically just that and is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: @ThomasAbend see my updates for an improved explanation and possible solution.